# Flutter list of String: How to add list of string in Text() functio

Tags: string, list, flutter, dart, mobile-application

I'm building List of questions for my Quizzler app and want to access the question one by one but can't able to add the list of my `questions` in `Text` function of my app... So how should I add my list of strings to `Text` to display them on screen one by one?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqCvA.png)

```
class QuizPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _QuizPageState createState() => _QuizPageState();
}

class _QuizPageState extends State<QuizPage> {
  List<Widget> scorekeeper = [];

  List<String> questions = [
    'You can lead a cow down stairs but not up stairs.',
    'Approximately one quarter of human bones are in the feet.',
    'A slug\'s blood is green.'
  ];

  int questionNum = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        const Expanded(
          flex: 3,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                questions[questionNum],
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ListView.builder` like this:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: questions.length,
  itemBuilder: (_, i) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          questions[i],
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 25.0,
            color: Colors.white, 
          ),
        )
      )
    );
  }
);
```

And remove key word `const`.

Comment: How can I be so dump man this is not the first time ```const``` caused an error but this time I just totally forgot about it and if I don't put ```const``` it shows waring but nevermind it's OK... And removing ```const``` was enough. Thank you!!